# Visual Basic Application

Tags: excel, vba

if someone could help me i will be pleased ...
I wrote a code in VBA that count a several things and this code must to highlight some cells in excell with an color but he didn't do that and i don't know why ...

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim studenti As Integer
    Dim prezenti As Integer
    Dim absenti As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    studenti = ActiveSheet.Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlTextValues).Rows.Count - 1

    prezenti = 0
    absenti = 0
    For i = 3 To studenti + 2
        If (Cells(i, 4).Value = "a") Then
            absenti = absenti + 1
            If (OptionButton2.Value = True) Then
                Cells(i, 3).Font.Color = vbGreen 'RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If

        If (Cells(i, 4).Value = "p") Then
            prezenti = prezenti + 1
            If (OptionButton1.Value = True) Then
                Cells(i, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            End If
        End If

        If (OptionButton3.Value = True) Then
            Cells(i, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: What are your "OptionButton2.Value" ? Check with debug if it come inside your conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Excel VBA code snippet will perform the core operation, namely: highlighting the absenti/presenti (text value "a" or "p" in Column D) with red/green text color:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim studenti As Integer
    Dim prezenti As Integer
    Dim absenti As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    studenti = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To studenti + 2
        If (Cells(i, 4).Value = "a") Then
            Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'RED
        ElseIf (Cells(i, 4).Value = "p") Then
            Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'GREEN
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can modify it further for your purpose adding business logic (all that OptionButton.Value, counters, etc.).

Hope this will help. Best regards

Comment: Yeah this works, but if i change to highlight (cells i, 3) this doesn't work ...
But thanks for help anyway ...

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: Do cells(i, 3) have any conditional formatting? This would override the font color property.